# Do Red Hat drivers work on CentOS?

Tags: centos, redhat, dell, drivers

I'm thinking on buying a [Dell PowerEdge T310](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/poweredge-t310/pd). It's marked as [certified hardware](https://hardware.redhat.com/show.cgi?id=632164) in Red Hat HCL, but I'd like to use CentOS. I know CentOS it's built from the RHEL sources, but do RHEL drivers work on CentOS?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, RHEL drivers will work with CentOS. Sometimes, I'll need to modify the `/etc/redhat-release` file on the CentOS system to match a RHEL servers' in order to get certain drivers/software to install or run, but otherwise, things are pretty compatible.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS is marketed as being binary compatible to RedHat. So while there is no guarantee for compatibnility (is there ever?), it is **very** likely that it works.